# Неодушевленные существительные м.р. на -а

Tags: грамматика

*Открываю отдельную тему исключительно потому, что обсуждение в комментариях беззащитно перед вандализмом. Так-то она на отдельный вопрос не тянет*.

В русском языке есть ряд неодушевленных существительных на -ина: голосина, домина, холодина, дымина...

Вопрос, собственно, вот в чем.

При согласовании в винительном падеже возникает проблема выбора формы.

а) Я видел большой домину?
б) Я видел большого домину?
в) Я видел большую домину?

Аванесов считает все эти формы неправильными или сомнительными (по памяти даю, это в приложении к его словарю) и я с ним согласен, слух режут все три, где-то еще говорят об использовании женского рода (вариант в) как единственно возможном.

То, что форма самого существительного возможна только на "-у", это понятно, другого первое школьное (оно же второе академическое) склонение не предоставляет, одушевленность тут ни при чем.  
Но вот как быть с прилагательным?

Да, вот еще что.
Боюсь, что предложение использовать исключительно женский род во многом повязано на небезызвестной строчке 
*Мою краснокожую паспортину.*
Но сдается мне что окказионализм(?) Владимира Владимировича никак не может быть аргументом.

//=========  (Антивандальная копия)

Грумант, а вы не пробовали иногда свои мысли излагать по сути вопроса? Я не принимаю, слов, обращенных к народу, как аргумент.
В таких случаях обычно "Народ безмолвствует".

Чем Ваше личное "лбина" лучше занесенных в словарь "домина" или "голосина"?

Кстати, если говорить о нем, в Вашей контексте "лбина" - почти наверняка одушевлен. Что в принципе исключает его из рассмотрения. С одушевленными существительными проблем при согласовании нет.

//=========  
[[@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F),
Признаться, я совсем не удовлетворен ответом, почему - писал. 
Но коли интерес себя исчерпал, пусть будет принятым Ваш ответ, по крайней мере он не вызывает явного отторжения в смысле подхода... Хотя вывод, имхо, рассуждениям не соответствует.

Comment: Вообще, вопрос прекрасный... Ресурс явно нацелен на значительное повышение, а то и удвоение ВВП. Скоро всех обгоним и перегоним!  
Народ, давай еще, подваливай спорных моментов СЛРЯ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот какими после некоторого размышления показались мне неодуш. существительные м. рода на А.

Во-первых, их мужской род - вещь весьма УСЛОВНАЯ, так как во всех падежах м.род дублируется ж. родом: этот домина  и эта домина, этого домины и этой домины и т.д.

Во-вторых, в В.п. они вообще НЕ ИМЕЮТ формы м.рода (только форма ж.рода): вижу большую домину. Это можно объяснить следующим образом.

Рассмотрим три предложения: (1)Я вижу молодого мужчину. (2)Я вижу молодого человека. (3)Я вижу этого домину. Предложение (3) аналогично предложению (1), но при этом  вызывает наше резкое неприятие.

Всё дело в том, что форма прилагательного на -ОГО  "вижу молодого, вижу этого" в нашем сознании прочно связана с ОДУШЕВЛЕННОСТЬЮ предмета, так как большинство одушевленных существительных м. рода относятся ко 2-ому склонению,  и, соответственно, ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ на -ОГО  в форме В.п. эту одушевленность как бы "выражает": вижу молодого человека. И в выражении "вижу этого домину" нам представляется некий одушевленный "домИну".

Поэтому остается одно решение: в В.п. считать "домину" существительным ж.рода: вижу эту домину.

Comment: *В своих поисках я набрел на огромный, мрачного вида, домина.* (В.п., неодуш., м.р.)  
Есть "неприятие", София?

Comment: Мое неприятие немного уменьшает распространенный ряд определений, но даже в этом случае я бы не стала пользоваться В.падежом. А теперь давайте этот ряд уберем: я набрел на домина. Как-то не очень звучит.

Comment: Такие слова редкость, поэтому чуть непривычно, только и всего. Можно специально начать придумывать подобные формы и дело наладится. Столбина, например.  
*Обошел высоченный столбина*.

Comment: София, но вы сначала **постулируете** женский род и отсутстсвие мужского (ваше во-1-х И во-2-х), а потом на основание этого постулата делаете выводы от том, что так и надо. Это рекрсивная ловля себя за хвост.       
  
Давайте начнем с обоснований вашего "во-первых" и "во-вторых". Если оно будет, обоснование это, то все остальное будет едва ли не самоочевидно.

Да, варианты типа "я набрел на домина" исключите сразу. В первом (школьном) склонении нет  такой формы в принципе. Что для мужского рода, что для женского. Это очередной грумантизм.

Comment: Если я буду "постулировать", то кто меня будет слушать, а на самом деле я цитирую Русскую грамматику, § 1185 (АКАДЕМИЯ НАУК СССР, ИНСТИТУТ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА). Я цитату и ссылку уже приводила, позволю еще раз вкратце: "Существительные муж. р. на -ина с ув. знач. типа домина  изменяются по II скл., выступая при этом в и. п. и во всех косв. пад., кроме вин., как сущ. то муж., то жен. р.: им. п.: этот и эта домина; род. п.: этого и этой домины и т.д. В вин. п. нормальна только форма на -у с согласованием по жен. р. (эту домину)". Вполне разумное решение, я его просто попыталась объяснить.

Comment: Не важно, кого вы цитируете.
Если вы принимаете написанное там как постулат, значит постулируете. дальнейшие разговоры не требуются. 
Если можете объяснить (обговорить, доказать) сказанное там - начните с этого.

Comment: К сожалению, у нас почти вся лингвистика-наука построена в виде постулатов, которые трудно отличить от эмпирических наблюдений. В частности, наша тема точно должна быть связана с записью практической грамматики, а не являться чистой теорией. (Интересно было бы подтвердить академическое правило реальными примерами). Поэтому ОБОСНОВАНИЯ "во-1-х И во-2-х" не требуется, будем считать, что это  наблюдение за живой речью. А далее, по логике вещей, обычно выдвигается версия-гипотеза, объясняющая наблюдаемый факт.

Comment: К сожалению - или не к сожалению, это другой вопрос.
Давайте зерна от плевел отличать.
 Если мы постулируем, что то это уже не подлежит дальнейшему обсуждению. 
Поэтому вывод типа "Я постулирую, что Сократ смертен, и потому знаю, что Сократ смертен" большой информативности в себе не несет.     
Если Вы исходно постулируете, что там возможен только женский род, то не стоит употреблять столько слов, чтобы в конечно счете прийти к выводу, что там там возможен только женский род.   
Простите, я не знаю, как еще это объяснить.

Comment: Вы спросили: "Но вот как быть с прилагательным"? Я вам ответила, как с ним быть, но у Вас мой ответ не вызвал интереса. Это суть, а все остальное - софистика. Вы или не согласны с объяснением, или делаете вид, что не согласны.

Comment: Ответили. на уровне постулата. 
Достаточно было одной фразы "Так считает АГ". В принципе я не возражаю, это можно считать позицией.  Но после этого надо ставить точку а не накручивать на этот тезис псевдологические построения, чтобы к нему же и прийти. Вот я о чем.

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке не так много неодушевленных существительных мужского рода на -ина. Например, *дымина*. Есть устойчивый оборот с этим словом, как раз в винительном падеже :

> М. А. Шолохов. Тихий Дон. Книга четвёртая (1928-1940)
> Ну, никак, несут его черти, и, небось, **пьяный в дымину**.

Надобно отметить, что суффикс -ин(а) придает словам не только "увеличивающее" значение, но и - вольно или невольно - меняет род с мужского на женский (скот - скотина, холод - холодина, дым - дымина и тд), поэтому однозначно определить род *домины*, *голосины*, *хлебины* - весьма проблематично. Очевидно, в этом конкретном винительном падеже не следует употреблять согласованные определения мужского рода, только и всего. Если без них никак не обойтись, всегда можно применить конструкцию с другим падежом. *Проехать не смогли, уперлись в домину*. *Передо мной возвышался казенный облезлый домина*.
Какие еще есть в словарях и текстах примеры подобных слов?
*Лбина*, мужской род...
В русской литературе нашелся замечательный отрывок с *лбиной* :

**Андрей Белый**
**Московский чудак**

> Что за вид?
> Он, как видно, не стригся, давно отрастая клоками; тяжелая морда; меж щечных бугров, как на корточках, - нос: диковырком! Казалось, что вычихнет; глазки, засевшие в щелках, готовились выстрелить. Но их очки защищали; свирепо и зверски карели моржовьи усы, борода; и, невидные, шлепали губы; **круглеющий лбина, как камень, способный и стену пробить**, - в дыбах косм, и свирепо, и зверски коричневых, да, - голова для гиганта; росток - очень мал: шеи - нет; перебито плечо; подскочило другое под ухо; весь корпус - пропыженный; коротки руки; одна - за спиною; другая - в сплошном вертунце - передрагивает дергунцами, пускающими карандашик вподброску; отчетливый пузик на брошенных вправо и влево ногах; желто-карий пиджак; желто-карий жилетец; крахмал - отложной.
> Черный галстучек - бантиком.
> Да - коротыш, с головой, кверху задранной!
> Думалось: - Вот так картинища!

Женский род для *лбины* не подходит, что ни говори.
*Уперся в лбину*.
Получается, что единственное слово на -ина "истинно" мужского рода - **лбина**. Не скажешь ведь : *суровая лбина*. Народ, как думаешь?
Заглянем в словарь Даля за справкой о *лбине* :

> **Лби'на**, лобови'на **ж**. верхъ или сводъ лба, самая выпуклость, округлая возвышеность;
> || выпуклость, округлость въ видѣ лба.
> || **Лбина м. лбища, увел.**
> Лби'ще ср. волж. гористый, обрубистый, крутоярый мысъ; отвѣсный, крутой берегъ, выдавшаяся скала.
> Лби'ща м. увел. лобъ.

Ефремова не так многословна :

> Толковый словарь русского языка под редакцией Т. Ф. Ефремовой
>
> ЛБИНА 
> лбина [лбина] м. разг. Увелич. к сущ.: лоб (1*1).

Как видим, возможны варианты смыслоприменения. В спорных случаях слова мужского рода с *увеличительным значением* лучше конструировать с помощью суффикса *-ищ(е)* : *домище, лбище, голосище*.

Дополнение.
Поскольку вопрос оказался действительно интересным, как я и сказал еще вчера (см. выше), то подведу окончательный личный вывод.
Неодушевленные существительные на -ина мужского рода, типа *домина, велосипедина, диванина etc*, должны иметь согласованные определения в В.п. в соответствии с формой И.п. : 
***Гигантский футбольный стадионина*** *вобрал в глубокую чашу целый город со всеми окраинами и медленно пожевывал свою жвачку.* (Им. падеж)
*Вошедши в просторную светлую горницу, Афанасий уставился на резной, чудно размалеванный всякими видами* ***ружейный сундучина***, *будто бы говоривший : я здесь главный!* (Вин. падеж)

Comment: Грумант, а вы не пробовали иногда свои мысли излагать по сути 
вопроса?  Я не принимаю, слов, обращенных к народу, как аргумент.   
В таких случаях обычно "Народ безмолвствует".  

Чем Ваше личное "лбина" лучше занесенных в словарь "домина" или "голосина"?

Кстати, если говорить о нем, в Вашей контексте "лбина" - почти наверняка одушевлен. Что в принципе исключает его из рассмотрения. С одушевленными существительными проблем при согласовании нет.

Ой, сохранюсь я во избежание вандализма. Так что не старайтесь.

Comment: Я думаю, что народ достаточно свободно обращался со словами на ИНА, делегируя им то мужской, то женский род. (А уж Владимир Владимирович (Маяковский) со своей краснокожей паспортиной и вовсе не утруждал себя подобными вопросами). Здесь главное -  это чтобы явно не нарушалась  формальная сочетаемость близко стоящих слов.

Comment: Вот, к примеру, слово "домина". Мужской род для него очень подходит, не хочется от него отказываться.  Но сочетаемость с прилагательным не нарушается только в И.п., а хочется применить и В.п. Но можно построить предложение так, чтобы несочетаемость НЕ БРОСАЛАСЬ В ГЛАЗА, например: "Сосед такой домина отгрохал". Поставили дополнение перед сказуемым, и вроде неплохо звучит. Для сравнения: Сосед построил такую домину (стиль академический). И кстати: А ПОЧЕМУ НАРОД ВСЕГДА  БЕЗМОЛВСТВУЕТ?

Comment: *Высоченный столбина, попавшийся на моем пути, я обошел с правой стороны.*  
София, я согласен с подобной вуалировкой В.п.)))

Comment: А вот "паспортина" - несомненно женский. Как "скотина" от скот. Так что это другое. Или "храмина" от "храм".

Comment: Скотина вообще из другой оперы. Как и машина, и картина)))

Comment: Разумеется, из другой оперы *скотина*) В прямом смысле - слово ж. рода, которое употребляется и в ед., и во "мн. числе" (в собирательном смысле). *Бессловесная скотина. Иди, накорми скотину*. В переносном - слово общего рода : *грязная скотина, он такой скотина*.

Answer (score 1):

Может, повторю уже сказанное кем-то.. Но разве домина уже не подразумевает "огромный, большой"?? 
Вообще, эти слова на - ина имеют явную эмоциональную окраску, выражают отношение говорящего к предмету: вот это домина! вот так холодина! Здесь акцент идет на величину, силу, интенсивность, уже заложенную в форме слова, поэтому оно как бы уже включает в себя прилагательное. Поэтому употреблять еще одно прилагательное в сочетании с таким словом - имхо, ошибка.

Comment: Все (или почти все) так. 
Но, во-первых, не ошибка, а фигура речи (эмфаза,). 
Во-вторых, значение "-ина" не обязательно сводится к огромности, может означать грубость, брутальность чего-то (сравните, например, "мужичина").
В-третьих, вопрос не о том. Замените на любое другое прилагательное. "Кирпичный домина" или "жуткий холодина" (или "жуткая"?) - все вопросы останутся.

Comment: я написала: здесь акцент идет на величину, силу, интенсивность - читайте внимательно.
ну если уж все-таки по существу вопроса, то наверное корректно употреблять в том же роде, что и первоначальное слово. То есть Дом - м.р., значит и Домина - м.р. и т.п.

Comment: Я всегда читаю внимательно. Чего и Вам желаю.
Сказал что не по существу, потому, что вы прицепились к одному единственному прилагательному из миллиона возможных. 

А если уж "по существу" то вопрос был в том, каким должен быть винительный падеж.

Comment: я вижу, как внимательно вы читаете: из трех прилагательных выбрали одно и к нему прицепились.

Comment: Лбина  вполне  себе  женского  рода.  Можно  сказать:" Этот  тип  такая  тупая  лбина!.."  По  аналогии  к  слову  туполобый.