# Существуют ли неодушевлённые существительные муж. рода первого склонения?

Tags: склонение, существительные, род, одушевленность

Подумал недавно, что в школе объясняли: 1-е склонение — это существительные мужского и женского рода с окончанием -а/-я. Но сходу не смог вспомнить слов муж. р. первого склонения. Загуглил и нашел несколько примеров (дядя, папа, судья), но все они одушевлённые. А существительных жен. р. первого склонения много и одушевлённых (мама, швея), и неодушевленных (ягода, сковорода).

Стало интересно, существуют ли вообще неодушевлённые существительные муж. р. первого склонения? Гугл/Яндекс ничего полезного не выдали. И второй вопрос: чем вызвано отсутствие или крайняя редкость слов этой категории?

Comment: Продублирую здесь ссылку на предыдущее обсуждение. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31741

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Неодушевленные существительные с окончаниями на -а существуют, но давайте пока оставим вопрос, к какому склонению их отнести и каким образом вообще установить их грамматическую неодушевленность.

Во-первых, это "увеличительные" формы на "-ина" некоторых слов мужского рода.
"Домина", "громина", "дымина" - и т.д. когда-то я нашел штук пять таких форм в словаре Лопатина, остальные же, хотя словарями и не фиксируются, безусловно возможны.

Во-вторых, некоторые одушевленные слова с подобными окончаниями допускают окказиональное использование в качестве неодушевленных. Например, "папа" - в профессиональном жаргоне электриков/электронщиков имеет значение **"мужской" разъем**.

Но как убедиться в неодушевленности и грамматическом роде таких существительных? Это то, почему я оговорился в начале о сложностях с определением грамматических категорий таких слов. Категория грамматической одушевленности проявляется только у существительных мужского рода второго склонения, у них в винительном падеже единственного числа падежная форма совпадает с формой родительного, а не именительного падежа. Аналогичное происходит и со словами любого рода во множественном числе, но там категория рода очень слабо выражена, настолько слабо, что многие авторы вообще сомневаются в её существовании в современном языке.

Существует, кстати, и одно одушевленное слово среднего рода. Это слово **"дитя"**. У него тоже сложности с определением одушевленности (исторически оно не было одушевленным), но в современном употреблении оно проявляет некоторые признаки грамматической одушевленности: его винительный падеж не совпадает с именительным. Поскольку в современном языке у категории одушевленности практически не осталось другой функциональной нагрузки, то этот признак - отличие формы винительного падежа от формы именительного (в единственном и/или множественном числе) и взят за основу. *Чтобы была понятна вся сложность и неоднозначность этого подхода упомяну, что исторически функционал у категории неодушевленности был больше, а винительный падеж не совпадал ни с именительным ни с родительным даже у слов мужского рода, грамматическая омонимия возникла в силу утраты некоторых звуков и форм, но ранее современное определение одушевленности не проходило бы.*

Теперь смотрите, какие сложности возникают при использовании обозначенного признака одушевленности в отношении разбираемой группы слов.

И. Огромный домина, двухконтактный папа
Р. Огромного домины, двухконтактный папа
Д. Огромному домине, двухконтактному папе
В. ???? домину, ???? папу

С винительным - ерунда получается.

Грамматика вроде бы требует соблюдения хотя бы одного из двух правил согласования.
Либо *"Вижу огромный домину"* - форма прилагательного винительного неодушевленного; видимо, это теоретически правильно но язык категорически отказывается его произносить из-за непривычности сочетания.
Либо *Вижу огромного домину* - но это же форма прилагательного при **одушевленном** существительном!
Вариант *Вижу огромную домину* не рассматривается, это вообще женский род.

Таким образом, указанные слова безусловно существуют имеют первый ("женский") тип склонения, но их грамматический род и особенно одушевленность определяется лишь с некоторой оговоркой. Хотя вот Аванесов, еще в середине прошлого века обративший внимание на эти слова, относит их **к неодушевленному мужскому роду**.

Оказывается этот вопрос уже обсуждался.
[Неодушевленные существительные м.р. на -а](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31741)

По сути я повторил сказанное ранее. 
Но там есть пример употребления из Маяковского: "Мою краснокожую паспортину, который вряд ли можно признать грамматически показательным. "Паспортина" это что-то действительно женского рода, чего никак нельзя признать за "доминой" или "дыминой".

Напротив, вики-словарь знает пример употребления оных в мужском роде:

> Вон какой домина занесли, — сказал он, как будто он отчасти был
>   виновником этой постройки и гордился этим. Л. Н. Толстой,
>   «Воскресение», 1899 г.

Персонаж Толстого явно чувствует грамматику неодушевленности лучше Владимира Владимировича М.

**UPD**

Ой...
Какой я материал по теме нашел!

[Еськова](https://books.google.ru/books?id=STRqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA515&lpg=PA515&dq=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BD+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=aJBb4QO4VB&sig=HGG7Segdw_etVDY3vx_b3s42YHs&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDkpLcuJbcAhXGJlAKHf0DBscQ6AEwAnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8&f=false)

Сам не проникся еще, не разобрался, но Наталья Александровна - авторитет безусловный, если что обнаружу необозначенное - добавлю сюда.

Ага, понятно. Еськова вслед за Зализняком вводит понятие "согласовательного" грамматического рода, который отличается от привычного нам морфологического. Это позволяет в простых терминах объяснить проблему, возникающую при грамматическом согласовании таких слов, но, однако, не разрешить её. Проблема остается.

@grizzly

По поводу [словаря Еськовой](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vFimCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA489&lpg=PA489&dq=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5,%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5...&source=bl&ots=wlMkvoEg0-&sig=e4CSh8B6P2bniJyRgZMEqDyg_ys&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp_sK-15bcAhWDJVAKHVNrDMYQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5...&f=false)

и этого.

> Кстати, проверять удобнее по винительному множественного числа.
>   Например: "вижу первых лиц государств..."

*проверять удобнее* - проверять надо по обоим числам. Иначе мы теряем группу слов с колебаниями в одушевленности. А у Еськовой - да, там интересная формулировка "неодушевленное, но ведет себя как одушевленное". Это говорит о том, что она опять использует два разных понятия одушевленности - в данном случае это некая "согласовательная" одушевленность. Она есть и у слова "дитя", но у слова "дитя" присутствует в современном языке и форма "вижу новорожденного дитя", что (пока) совершенно невозможно со словом "лицо".

Там другой есть пример интересный: "Чудовище, чудище...". Еськова пишет, что эти слова испытывают колебания, но в единственном числе "вижу этого чудовища" выглядит как минимум допустимым. То есть "чудовище" ближе к безусловной  одушевленности, которую имеет "дитя", чем "лицо".
Допускаю, что использованная мной формулировка для слова "лицо" ("однозначно неодушевленное") не совсем четкая, но я говорил именно об **абсолютной, бесспорной и безоговорочной неодушевленности слова**, подобной той, что у слова "дитя".

Короче, смысл сказанного мной понятен (а мне понятно, что сказали вы), но чтобы закрыть вопрос с этими словами, необходимо прежде уточнить само  понятие грамматической одушевленности.

Comment: *Существует, кстати, и одно одушевленное слово среднего рода.* — ещё **лицо** (совершеннолетнее, например), ну и несколько слов типа **животное**, **млекопитающее** и т.п.

Comment: @grizzly, а как вы докажете одушевленность (грамматическую!) лица? "Вижу совершеннолетнего лиц**а**?". Нет, лицо - слово неодушевленное во всех значениях. Вот что касается животных и прочих - тут, да, есть о чем поразмышлять.  "Вижу это животное" против "вижу этого животного". Но обычно второй случай трактуется все-таки как переход в мужской род, а не просто приобретение одушевленности.

Comment: *а как вы докажете одушевленность (грамматическую!) лица?* — приведу цитату из книги Еськовой: "существительное **лицо** в значении «человек» ведет себя как одушевленное, но в сочетании *действующее лицо* испытывает колебание..." (гуглится; поля комментария слишком узки, чтобы поместить прямую ссылку :)

Comment: Кстати, проверять удобнее по винительному множественного числа. Например: "вижу первых лиц государств...".

Comment: @grizzly я ответ в "тело" вопроса перенес. В комментариях дискуссия может развернуться, чего не очень любят модераторы. А вопрос заслуживает лучшей участи.

Answer (score 0):

Приведу в отдельном ответе некоторые наблюдения по словарям. (Слишком много текста для комментария.)

Кроме "усилительного" суффикса **-ина**, больше распространен другой (омонимичный, но грамматически отличающийся), обозначающий один элемент из собирательной совокупности: бисер — бисерина, ворс — ворсин(к)а, (вино)град — (вино)градина и т.п. Здесь образуется слово с другим значением, так что нет проблемы с тем, что род меняется. Но нашелся один пример, в котором, кажется, происходит смешение этих значений: 
**кирпич** — *кирпИчина* (экземпляр кирпича, ж.р.) и 
*кирпичИна* (большой кирпич, одни словари фиксируют м.р., другие ж.р., третьи допускают оба варианта).

В словаре Лопатина примерно 700 слов м.р. на "-а".

Среди увеличительных суффиксов еще есть такие, как в словах "ветрюга"/"ветряга", "штормяга", "холодюга"/"холодюка"; во всех этих случаях м.р. кажется неудобным и легко использовать — как отдельное слово неясного происхождения, а не образованное "усилительным" суффиксом — ж.р., типа "ночью была ужасная холодюга". Возможно, по этой причине в словарях также имеется разнобой в определении рода этих слов.

Есть еще уменьшительные типа "заяц" -- "зайчишка", но неод. в этой форме оканчиваются на "-о": "дом" -- "домишко". Интересный пример из Лопатина, когда есть и од. и неод.:
  **кулач'ишка**, -и, р. мн. -шек, м. (человек)
  **кулач'ишко**, -а и -и, мн. -шки, -шек, м. (сжатая кисть руки)

И напоследок самое интересное — пример заимствования:

**эспада**, -ы, м.

В Викисловаре тоже написано, что м.р., но парадигма приведена для слова "эспад" (без "-а") — по-видимому, ошибка.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь два раза. Во-первых, "Убийца" в таком применении сохраняет все признаки **грамматической** одушевленности. А во-вторых, примеры из словаря Лопатина - в моем ответе.

Comment: Выше комментарий на удалённый вчера ответ.